# Android Udp : How to receive datagramPacket from LAN

Tags: android, udp, client, lan, datagram

I have an UDP server wrote in C langage which broadcasts paquets over my LAN every 5seconds, on port 3001.

i'm creating an android application as UDP client, which is listening on port 3001 (in the AsyncTask thread) and it's running until the receive() method, no data seems to be detected on this port.

Here is my code :

```
private class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        String receivedString = "";

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        DatagramSocket clientSocket;
        try {
            while(true){
                clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(5000);
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                        receiveData.length);
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                receivedString = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            }


        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.v("SocketExceptionOccured", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            //clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("IOExceptionOccured", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            //clientSocket.close();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), receivedString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        return null;

    }

}
```

I test my code with my own device for debug, with USB cable.

I've tested my server with a simple UDP client (in C) running on my computer, and the communication is ok.

I don't know why this code doesn't work. Has someone an idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you mean, it doesn't work? show some Logs on both sides of the connection to see where it could go wrong

Answer (score 0):

You're never leaving the `while` loop. You're message is probably received, and after it, the loop causes the datagramsocket to listen again.

Comment: The problem comes form the device, if i run a simple udp client in java like this one :

Answer (score 0):

Don't create and close the socket every time around the loop. Create it first and close it afterwards. At present there are windows of time during which the socket doesn't exist, so datagrams to it are dropped: also, all queued datagrams are dropped every time you close it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. You need to add permissions in the android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Also enable broadcasts in the socket.

```
clientSocket.setBroadcast(true);
```

Like everyone else before me mentioned, your code also never leaves the while loop, so it never goes to the the line where the toast is displayed.Remember that you CANNOT show Toast messages from doInBackground as this is accessing the UI Thread, you can only do so from the postExecute and preExecute functions. This will cause your application to crash. To check the data you receive you can either debug it or log it.

Your final doInBackground should be something like this

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    String receivedString = "";

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

    DatagramSocket clientSocket;
    try {
        while(true){
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(5000);
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                    receiveData.length);
            clientSocket.setBroadcast(true);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            receivedString = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            Log.i("Received String= "+receivedString);
        }


    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.v("SocketExceptionOccured", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        //clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("IOExceptionOccured", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        //clientSocket.close();
    } finally{
        if(clientSocket!=null){
           clientSocket.close();
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

Now when you check your logs, you should be able to see the value of the string received.